# First Order Logic Consistency Big Problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

as i read some tutorial material on First Order Logic, i deduce that the following formula was consistent in FOL except the third one. am i right? i have doubt about the first one. any idea? thanks to all experts.

> 1. $\bigl\{\exists y\exists x\forall z\,\bigl(C(x,y,z) \to \neg C(x,x,x)\bigr)\bigr\}$
> 2. $\bigl\{ \forall x \bigl(A(x) \to B(x)\bigr), \forall x \bigl(A(x) \to \neg B(x)\bigr)\bigr\}$
> 3. $\{\forall x\,A(x)\} \cup \{\neg A(t) \mid t \text{ is a term}\}$
> 4. $\{\forall x\exists y\, B(x,y) \to \neg \exists y \forall x \,B(x,y), \exists x\,B(x,x)\}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: tHX LOTS SHANUN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We construct a model for 1).  The (underlying set of) the structure $M$ has one element $a$. The interpretation $C_M$ of the predicate symbol $C$ is false at $(a,a,a)$. Then the sentence 1) is true in $M$.

Similarly, we can construct models for 2) and for 4).  In 4), let $M$ have two elements, $0$ and $1$. The interpretation of the predicate symbol $B$ is true at $(0,0)$, and false at the pairs $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. Then $\forall x\exists y B(x,y)$ is false in $M$, so the implication  $\forall x\exists y B(x,y)\longrightarrow \lnot \exists y\forall x B(x,y) $ is true in $M$.

Comment: Dear André Nicolas, would you please add more detail? i want to know much more ! i means if survey on each formula that consistent or inconsistent..

Comment: The standard way to show that a set of sentences is consistent is to exhibit a model. I did it for the first sentence since you expressed uncertainty in that case. Which of 2 or 4 do you need a model for?

Comment: would you please say for 2 and 3 and 4? i think the just 3 is inconsistent.

Comment: ِDear André Nicolas, surely the third one is inconsistent with FOL?

Comment: The answer to 3) is presentation-dependent. If by term your course means variable-free term, then 3) could be trivially satisfiable if there are no such terms in the language. If terms include variable symbols, then the set is not satisfiable, there is no model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can i have your email address André  ?

Comment: You are welcome. It is usually easy enough, if you have a question, to post it. As you have seen, answers usually come quickly.

Comment: one of my TA need some Clever person for employee to solve some problem for his student in Twente University. i think you are the best option and if you prefer send me your ID for contact. i'm sorry for my poor english :)